# Restrict maximum ram on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, memory-limit

I have a problem with my ram on my windows7 64bit - it's too much ;)

Some of my old software can't handle the 8gb of ram i have, but there is a possibility to limit it, so windows uses all in all only, let's say 2048 mb of the ram. (If I look in the taskmanager, there should be only 2 gb of ram available)

Do you know, where I can do this settings?

Thanks, Karl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click Start, Run
2. Type `MSConfig`
3. Go to the `Boot` tab
4. Select your OS
5. Click Advanced
6. Check the Maximum memory checkbox
7. Enter an amount (in megabytes, I believe)